# Can I block browser UI thread until Angularjs promise finishes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multithreading

I have a timing issue with a form with multiple input boxes. Some input-boxes are disabled by default.
When a user presses the TAB key to focus next input-box, I want a promise to block the UI-thread until it has been resolved/rejected.
This is because the focus-state (enabled/disabled) of the next input-box depends on the result of the http request in the previous input-box.
If the user types fast and presses the TAB-key, focus will be set to an already enabled input-box further down the chain instead of the next one.

The promise is used in a $http request and when the response arrives, logic will decide if the next input-box should be enabled or not.

Every input-box uses ng-blur to detect loss of focus. The directive for the input-box also keeps track of the search-promise and I have access to it in the blur method inside the directive.

Can it be done?

Comment: You can add keydown or keypress events and intercept the TAB key.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can offer is the standard `ng-cloack`. Where you will avoid displaying things until they are ready.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

The other option is you managing "manually" the display of things with things like a spinner or simply by hiding controls until things "are ready".

Comment: I was thinking about disabling all fields and change focus to next manually when the promise finishes, but it will probably confuse users with a kind of "jumpy" focus behavior. The reason the next field is disabled by default is because it depends on data in the previous one and I want to instruct users to fill in the correct (key) field first.

Answer (score 1):

You should not block the whole UI. A synchronous AJAX request would do what you want, but [it has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

You could just block (disable/read-only) the input field that needs to be validated while the request is pending. You should show some indication besides the grayed out field so the user understands that there's an action pending.